# How to dismiss OneDrive notification in Windows Defender Security Centre?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area, windows-defender

For a few days now the icon for Windows Defender in the bottom right of my taskbar shows a yellow warning sign ⚠️ (which usually popped up when any problems were detected). When clicking on it, it just shows a message that wants me to set up OneDrive. But I do not want to get a OneDrive account.

[image]

There is an option to dismiss this message, but whenever I boot my computer, it is there again. Is there a way to completely dismiss this message, such that the warning sign only pops up again if there are actual problems?

I fear that I end up ignoring the warning sign and missing the moment when there is an actual problem.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/windows-defender-warning-about-onedrive-does-not/0fb02e03-e825-4d9d-846b-48e4a9b6e669 ?

Comment: @user202729 There is nothing useful on that page.

Comment: This is the problem with Microsoft. They're so obsessed with owning your software and controlling your files and operating system that they work incessantly to take control or pressure you to relinquish it willingly.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact issue and found it difficult to find an answer to as well.  I was personally able to solve this by going to Add/Remove Programs and uninstalling OneDrive itself.

Comment: This worked for me. I had already uninstalled OneDrive months ago, and an automatic windows update decided to reinstall it...